# KML coordinates are off in a custom Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, kml

**EDIT: Turns out it was all because the coordinate translation functions in the javascript were written wrong. The author of the program has apparently fixed it.**

I'm trying to use KML files to display placemarks on a custom Google Maps map. The map was generated by a Minecraft mapping program called Unmined.

My problem lies with the positioning of placemarks. They are placed on the map in a position that doesn't seem to correlate with either the pixel or latitude/longitude coordinates of the map itself.

Here is an image showing my problem.

[image]

I loaded a KML with five placemarks defined. One in the middle (0,0), one in the top-left corner (-170,80), one in the top-right corner (170,80), one in the bottom-left corner (-170,-80), and one in the bottom-right corner (170,-80). The set of markers seems to be duplicated horizontally but from my experience that's standard with Google Maps. As far as I know, the range of valid coordinates in a KML file are from -180 to 180 longitude and -90 to 90 latitude, which means that any valid placemark would have to fall somewhere inside that rectangle. Except that rectangle barely intersects the map at all.

If you need access to the code I'm using, everything can be found in the source of http://tonyfox.ws/dt/kantomap/ (URL may not exist forever)

So am I just doing something catastrophically wrong or what?

On a related note, how does Google Maps decide where to place the map in the coordinate system when the map isn't an actual Earth map (like this Minecraft world map)? My map seems to range from about 14.5 to 19.5 longitude, and 25.5 to 28 latitude. Why such weird numbers?